# How do I update my graphics?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm pretty inexperienced with regards to graphics, so I tried a tutorial and ended up with this:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ide extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6804608149790007396L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    private boolean running = false;

    Graphics gr;

    public Ide(){
        new Window(WIDTH,HEIGHT,"Ide v0.1",this);
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        running = true;
        gr = this.getGraphics();
        gr.drawString("Hello", 100, 20);

    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        running = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ide();

    }
}
```

and this:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8255319694373975038L;

    public Window(int w, int h, String title, Minecraft_Function_Ide ide){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(ide);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ide.start();
    }
```

The "Hello" was working properly earlier but it isn't anymore, and I'm not sure if I'm just missing an update statement of some kind or if I'm doing the wrong thing altogether.

Anyone with more experience want to help out?

Comment: Your tutorial is wrong; don't `getGraphics` it's not how custom painting is done, depending on what you're trying to do, it's even inadvisable to extend from `Canvas`

Comment: I would suggest starting with [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works and how you can use it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better answered via one or more appropriate tutorials, like [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link... guess that's what I get for youtube tutorials :|

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you never invoke the `paint()` method on your `gr` object. But that wouldn't explain why you got it to work in the first place.

Try adding this line at the end of your `start()` method:

```
gr.paint();
```